# Desc primary key of all tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I want to get the result of **Desc** for only specific columns of each table in the information schema, let's say Primary Key.

Can this be done?

I tried things like

```
 SELECT * FROM (DESC TABLENAME) WHERE ....;
```

but it did not work.

Also I want this to work for all tables.

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by DESC?

Comment: Do you need sort in reverse (descending) ? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC aka DESCRIBE aka SHOW COLUMNS will not work in a subquery.
But SELECT will.
You can for example replace

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM t IN test LIKE '%2';
```

with

```
SELECT column_name AS `Field`, column_type AS `Type`,
is_nullable AS `Null`,
column_key as 'Key',
column_default AS `Default`, extra AS `Extra`
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'test'
AND table_name = 't'
AND column_name like '%2';
```

and you'll get the same thing.